# Recursive function with timeout and check RxJs Observable value polling

Tags: rxjs, observable, settimeout

I have the recursive function: `repeatAlert` that is called again if `data.answered === null`:

....
**Edit**

```
      this.repeatAlert(id).subscribe( val => console.log(val));
      console.log('1stCall Alert: ', new Date().getMinutes());
```

....

```
  find(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}ByAlertId/${id}`
  }

  repeatAlert(id: number) {
    this.find(id).subscribe((data: AlertInt) => {
       if (data.answered === null ) {
          this.sendNotification('Alert ', data.text);
          console.log('Call Alert: ', new Date().getMinutes(), data.id);

          setTimeout(() => {
            if (data.answered === null) {
              this.repeatAlert(id);
            }
          }, data.repeating * 1000 * 60);
       }
    });
  }
```

When I change the value of `data.answered` in the database, I can't read with this observable `find(id)` the change  of `data.answered`. So it keeps calling `repeatAlert` forever ...

**What am I doing wrong?**

Extra question: Is it better a loop or recursive function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing polling. I suggest something like following:

```
find(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}ByAlertId/${id}`;
}

repeatAlert(id: number) {
  // request data from the endpoint and execute necessary code
  const data$ = this.find(id).pipe(
    tap(data => {
      if (data.answered === null) {
        this.sendNotification('Alert ', data.text);
      }
    })
  );

  // polling will start if on the first try we don't have data.answered
  const startPolling = (duration: number) => timer(duration, duration).pipe(
    //take(10), // let's say we want to stop after 10 tries
    concatMap(() => data$),
    takeWhile(data => data.answered === null), // when to stop polling
  );

  // if data.answered is null on the first try switch to polling otherwise end
  return data$.pipe(
    switchMap(data => data.answered === null ?
      startPolling(data.repeating * 1000 * 60) :
      of(data)
    ),
  );
}
```

Also note that I changed your `repeatAlert`, it's better to return Observable from the method and subscribe yourself to avoid memory leaks. You should subscribe and unsubscribe yourself. Also, I suggest you to use `take(10)` for example so that polling doesn't continue indefinitely, it's up to you.

---

**`timer(dueTime, period)` works like this:** It will emit first event after `dueTime` and continue emitting events after every `period`.

**Edit** takeWhile condition is true and not condition is false

Comment: Great Anwser! @Goga. Do you have a suggestion where I can learn RxJS so well :-) ? I edit the question so you can see the result !

Comment: Hah, glad it helped. Lot's of real world usage experience, reading official api docs and articles about RxJS. I have created small list of good resources about RxJS for friend, have a look at it: https://gist.github.com/gogakoreli/5d7eb20d4aebb96c031ea813c82955de

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that this code is also working

```
  repeatAlert(id: number) {
    this.alertServ.find(id).subscribe((data: AlertInt) => {
      if (data.answered === null) {
        this.sendNotification( 'Alert ', data.text);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.repeatAlert(id);
        }, data.repeating * 1000 * 60);
      }
    });
  }
```

I forget in the backend to send the `data.answered` field ... so was always null