# Angular - Call function every 30 seconds but account for time taken to run the function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Angular 7 application and I am using RxJS.

I want to fetch a list of stuff from an endpoint every 30 seconds, but sometimes the request can take a while and I want to account for that time.

Example: if the request takes 10 seconds, then I want to call it again after 40 seconds (30 + 10), not 20 (30 - 10).

I am trying with:

```js
fetchList() {

   this.service.fetchListFromHttp()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.fetchList();
          }, 30000)
        )
      )
      .subscribe(
         result => this.list = result,
         err => this.logError(err)
      );
}
```

I would imagine that when the http requests, it would trigger another call to fetchInfo after 30 seconds, but what happens is that I get weird intervals. For instance, the funcion gets called every 10 seconds, or 20 seconds, and weird intervals like that.
I would assume that the interval would always be bigger then 30 seconds.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231259/recursive-function-with-timeout-and-check-rxjs-observable-value-polling/61234971#61234971

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting to your own backend? If you're the one who has coded the API to fetch information form, `socket.io` is probably what you're looking for to accomplish this.

Have you looked into using `RxJS`? it comes with Angular, I'm sure what you could accomplish something that fetches then pauses

something similar to this might work

`this.service.fetchInfoFromHttp().pipe(delay(30 * 60 * 10000), () => ...), repeat(Infinity))`

Here is the link to the documentation on RxJS

[RxJS delay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay)

[RxJS repeat](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/repeat)

[Socket.io](https://socket.io/)

EDIT: 
[How Can I make a Timer using an observable in Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240012/how-can-i-make-a-timer-using-an-observable-in-angular-9)

EDIT AGAIN:

Thanks for your comment [@goga-koreli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8578281/goga-koreli), maybe debounce will work

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debounce

Comment: This will delay first emit too, I believe he wants to receive value as soon as its arrived from the network.

Comment: Let me clarify, sorry. I have a RESTful service that I want to check every 30 seconds to see if there is new stuff. @SVNTY

Comment: @GogaKoreli Hmm, subscribing to a network update without the use of a socket is difficult, you could debounce the information if it's newer than 30 seconds but I think I'm out of ideas

Comment: @SVNTY what do you think about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Improving upon SVNTY's answer, you can do it like so:

```
fetchInfo() {
  const passAndWait = (data) => interval(30000).pipe(
    take(1),
    ignoreElements(), // this is needed to discard interval numbers
    startWith(data),
  )

  // get data from network pass it to subscriber and wait for specified time
  // repeat will start everything again when interval completes with take(1)
  this.service.fetchInfoFromHttp().pipe(
    concatMap((data) => passAndWait(data)),
    repeat(Infinity), 
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the (data). What value is it supposed to have? Also, won't interval(30000) gets triggered every 30000 seconds, and every time I call passAndWait a new interval gets created?

Comment: @Saita Ah, I thought you need to process data returned from the endpoint. If that's not the case you can just remove the data and startWith :) I will update the answer

Comment: I do have data returned from me endpoint. I am gonna update my question.

Comment: `ignoreElements` can be piped to interval to remove the noise as well.

Comment: @Phix Wow, thanks I wasn't aware of `ignoreElements` :)

Answer (score 0):

use observable from rxjs https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q714uq

```
import { interval, Subject, PartialObserver, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

after import libraries set interval to 30 then start after finish call your service when service get result again start interval

```
ispause = new Subject();
private time = 30;
timer: Observable<number>;
timerObserver: PartialObserver<number>;
ngOnInit(){
    this.timer = interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ispause)
      );    
    this.timerObserver = {         
      next: (_: number) => {  
         if(this.time==0){
           this.ispause.next;
           this.callservice();   
         }
         this.time -= 1;        
      }
    };
    this.timer.subscribe(this.timerObserver);    
}

callservice(){
  //after u get data
  this.service.fetchListFromHttp()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() =>
          this.time=30;
          this.timer.subscribe(this.timerObserver);
        )
      )
      .subscribe(
         result => this.list = result,
         err => this.logError(err)
      );

 }
```

Comment: Do you know why my example is having such strange behavior?

Comment: When i look at your. I colun't see any problem. U check in finalize pipe to finish request . u stop it 30 seconds and call it. U should use debugger to understand problem. finalize and timeout function may lead to the problem